# Page not found, my template is there but I see an Page Not Found error

Tags: python, django

I saw different Q&A about this error, but I couldn´t find one similar to my case.

I´m trying to create "read templates" from two classes, but I can´t. I already created the views and the models, but the templates don´t work.

- views:

```
def readCoberturas(request):

    cobert = Coberturas.objects.all()

    dicCoberturas = {"Coberturas": cobert}

    return render(request, "AppURC/readCoberturas.html", dicCoberturas)
```

- Model (Coberturas):

```
class Coberturas(models.Model):

    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    numeroPoliza = models.IntegerField()
    fechaContratacion = models.DateField()
    fechaVigencia = models.DateTimeField()
    detalle = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
        
         return f"Tipo de Cobertura: {self.tipo} | Poliza n°: {self.numeroPoliza} | Fecha alta: {self.fechaContratacion} | Vigencia hasta: {self.fechaVigencia} | Detalle: {self.detalle}"
```

- Url:

```
path('readCoberturas/',views.readCoberturas, name='ReadCoberturas'),
```

- Template:

```
{% load static %}

    {% block contenido %}

        {% for C in Coberturas %}
        
            <li>{{ c }}</li>

        {% endfor %}

    {% endblock %}
```

I hope I have made this sufficiently clear. Thanks to all!

Comment: Try to lowercase `c` here ` {% for c in Coberturas %}`

Comment: the url that I posted wasn´t the one relating to the error. The one that I really used was 

path('readCoberturas',views.readCoberturas, name='ReadCoberturas'), 

without "/" after the url readCoberturas. 
When I introduced the "/", the page works but using the GET method only. Thanks again.

Comment: @Eugenij thanks for your comment! it worked in a way jajaja. I fixed the mistake, but the error still happens. I was able to load the page adding the '/' in the url at the end of the template´s name.--> path('readCoberturas/',views.readCoberturas, name='ReadCoberturas'), <--- Even so, when I try to move to the homepage, the code collapse again under the same error "Page Not found" -->http://127.0.0.1:8000/AppSeguros/readCoberturas/home -- Seems like a GET method, and I need Post